# python people api quit working

Tags: python, google-people-api, apiclient

I have a python (2.7.10) code based on the "quickstart" example at https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python, which reads contacts from a gmail account.  It has been running every Sunday for months.  On 12/18/16, it failed.  The error message and lines leading up to it are:

```
...
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('people', 'v1', http=http,
    discoveryServiceUrl='https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')

results = service.people().connections().list(resourceName='people/me',
    requestMask_includeField='person.names,person.email_addresses',
    pageSize=160).execute()
```

**AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'connections'**

On entry to this code 'credentials' seems ok, but I am not skilled enough to really know.  credentials.invalid is false, which is what the code checks for.

My code did not change.  Did something happen to the build/discovery service?  Could the credentials have something to do with this?

This is on Windows 7.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messing around with it, I was able to get it to work with this change:

```
service.people().me().connections().list(pageSize=100).execute()
```

I'm not sure why the code was changed, or why it wasn't documented. I simply dug around calling `dir()` on each object.

Comment: Yes, that did it (and removing the resourceName argument)!  Thanks so much!!